# Unresolved reference: RecyclerView despite implementing support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I have a class in which RecyclerView is used but even in import an Unresolved reference error is displayed

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Gradle file contains implementation for it thou:

```
dependencies{
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add support:design to Gradle as well:

```
dependencies{
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   ...
}
```

Hope this will help you if you run into this problem as well